# Replace query string with file extension using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this link
`https://career.guru99.com/top-50-oops-interview-questions/?format=pdf`

I want to redirect it to
`https://career.guru99.com/pdf/top-50-oops-interview-questions.pdf`

I created the following htaccess rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} format=pdf [NC]
RewriteRule ^top-50-oops-interview-questions /pdf/top-50-oops-interview-questions.pdf? [R=301,L]
```

But the challenge is I have 200+ links and I will have to manually add so many entries in the htacess which also slow down the site. Is there some regular expression that can help with this?

I want `/?format=pdf` to be replaced with `.pdf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. I am going through variable `THE_REQUEST` and getting appropriate format value from it then while rewriting placing its value.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.*?)/\?format=([^\s]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%2%1.%2 [NE,QSD,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want `/?format=pdf` to be replaced with `.pdf`:

You may try this rule:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^format=(pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /%1/$1.%1? [R=301,END,NE]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /%1/$1.%1? [R=301,END,NE]` because he ask for file type in the end.